# android insert svg image from website (using syntask) to listview

Tags: android, web-services, listview, svg

I have a task the deadline tom ,please your help with that exception. i want to load a svg image and display it on listview

> com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVGParseException:
>   org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column
>   0: no element found
>               at com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVGParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>               at com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVGParser.getSVGFromInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)

// code //

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable> {

    ImageView image;

    DownloadImageTask(ImageView img)
    {
             image=img;

    }
    @Override
    protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            String urldisplay = params[0];
            final URL url = new URL(urldisplay);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromInputStream(inputStream,0,0);
            Drawable drawable = svg.createPictureDrawable();
            return drawable;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable drawable) {
        // Update the view

       image.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
       image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }
}
```

how to solve this problem?

Comment: We'd need to see the code and the file you're trying to parse (at least the first line of it).

Comment: //trying to download svg image http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/Eintracht_Frankfurt_Logo.svg      i add the code